# How should I implement a variable-spec VM

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Windows 10 in Virtualbox on an Ubuntu (18.04) host.  It's an old (9 years, but going strong and originally high spec) personal desktop being used unexpectedly for work.

Currently I'm mainly using it for light data-processing (e.g. plotting graphs in OriginLab), and the performance of basic Windows utilities is barely acceptable with 2 threads (of 8) and 4GB RAM (of 16).  The host is my main OS, and is OK with 6 cores/12GB but would definitely suffer if I gave most of the resources to the VM.

I anticipate a need to run more significant analyses and more demanding software in the VM (Autodesk Inventor 3D modelling) so would like to be able to turn up the performance for a session.  I can easily reboot the VM in anticipation of this.  All data is stored in a folder accessible to the host and all guest OSs (I also have an old Ubuntu guest to run something proprietary and  no longer supported).  Windows appears to be able to handle being booted on different rations of hardware to last time without issues in brief testing.

As it's a personal machine a major hardware upgrade is out of the question - so no new CPU/motherboard.  A RAM upgrade might be possible but all slots are full (4x4GB), so ~£50 would take me to 24GB or ~£100 to max out the motherboard at 32GB, I'm probably  CPU-limited.

*What's my best option for being able to switch a Windows VM between low-spec and high-spec operation?*  I've considered:

- Cloning the VM, setting one clone high-spec and one clone low-spec, and choosing which to boot

  - Downsides - disc space, every Windows update needs to run twice
- Changing the settings of the same VM before boot

  - Downsides: hassle every time.  If I forget to turn down the guest settings the host will slow down massively.
  - Could this be scripted?
- Is there another option I've missed?

Since a recent set of updates to Windows and the software I use it for, I have the same issue on a newer machine with Ubuntu 20.04 as the host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is so often the case, the solution was simple once I'd discovered the magic command.

VirtualBox VMs can be modified and started using [`vboxmanage`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html); settings are stored in an xml file that could be (but shouldn't be) edited directly.  With this in mind the solution is is a pair of shell scripts:

Win10Hi.sh:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "Win10Edu" --memory 8192
vboxmanage modifyvm "Win10Edu" --cpus 4
vboxmanage startvm "Win10Edu"
```

(12 GiB leads to an aborted boot, probably because the host can't dedicate that much)

and Win10Lo.sh:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "Win10Edu" --memory 4096
vboxmanage modifyvm "Win10Edu" --cpus 2
vboxmanage startvm "Win10Edu"
```

A little care or experimenting is needed regarding the number of CPUs - the manual says it should be the umber of physical cores excluding hyperthreading, but the number set by `vboxmanage` in configuration file reflects that in the GUI, and includes hyperthreading in the count of available cores.